# Correct way to call Ruby script in HTML

Tags: html, ruby, rubygems, mechanize

Is this the correct way to call a ruby script in an HTML file?

HTML

```
<form id="cse-search-box" action="mechanize.rb">
<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" class="mytext" />
<input id="search" type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background: url('search.png') no-repeat; width: 50px; height: 50px;">
</form>
```

Ruby

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

a.get('http://google.com/') do |page|
  search_result = page.form_with(:name => 'f') do |search|
    search.q = 'Hello world'
  end.submit

  search_result.links.each do |link|
    puts link.text
  end
end
```

Instead of executing the Ruby code, it displays the Ruby code in the browser in text. Is this possibly because I incorrectly installed the Ruby gem or because I'm calling the .rb file incorrectly with `action="mechanize.rb"` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not standard and needs some more pieces to work.

The form action is a URL to which the form data will be submitted.  Something needs to be waiting to accept that HTTP request and return the document that you want.  What's happening is that your web server gets a request for "mechanize.rb", and the only way it knows to handle this request is to return the contents of the file.

To run the Ruby code, you need something like a web application framework -- in this case, Rails is the obvious choice.  So you could rewrite the form to use a URL like "/mechanize", and make sure there's a controller to handle that request.  The controller would grab the form data and produce some output, using code much like mechanize.rb, but using a view to render the output.